# Finding Xpath of element within angular table

Tags: selenium, xpath

Hoping somebody is able to help me

I am trying to find the Xpath within the table below

[image]

I need to create an XPath query which will return the entitlements transferred box which contains the text 'entitlements @' but the row in the table must contain the Hide Externally checkbox

Therefore I wish to ignore the first row in the table but return the entitlements transferred box for the 2nd and 3rd rows etc.

Below is the HTML code for the table

```
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1"><a href="#" class="sortorder" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('transferorBusinessId',reverse)">Transferor Business ID</a></th>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1"><a href="#" class="sortorder" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('transfereeBusinessId',reverse)">Transferee Business ID</a></th>
                        <th class="text-right">Transfer Type</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Date of Transfer</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Effective Date</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Entitlements Transferred</th>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1">Group ID</th>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1"><a href="#" class="sortorder" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('yearOfTransfer',reverse)">Year of Transfer</a></th>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1">Leased Until</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Hide<br> Externally</th>
                        <th class="text-right"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer) --><tr ng-repeat="transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer)">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class="{'highlight' : transfer.transferorBusinessId == CisBusinessID }" class="highlight">622402</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class="{'highlight' : transfer.transfereeBusinessId == CisBusinessID }">661017</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">Lease</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">22/06/2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">13/04/2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">3.00 entitlements @ €242.55</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">513453</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2017</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="transfer.isTransferHiddenForExternal" ng-show="false" ng-click="changeVisisbilityOfTransferOnExternalScreen(transfer)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-hide">                        
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-show="true" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">Withdrawn</label>
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(166, 166, 166);" ng-show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" class="ng-hide"></label>
                            <div>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="showUndoModal(transfer)">Undo</a>

                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="executeWithdrawCommand(transfer)">Withdraw</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="showWithdrawModal(transfer)">Withdraw</a>


                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer) --><tr ng-repeat="transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer)">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class="{'highlight' : transfer.transferorBusinessId == CisBusinessID }" class="highlight">622402</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class="{'highlight' : transfer.transfereeBusinessId == CisBusinessID }">602024</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">Lease</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">18/04/2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">18/04/2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">11.00 entitlements @ €242.55</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">513453</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2017</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="transfer.isTransferHiddenForExternal" ng-show="true" ng-click="changeVisisbilityOfTransferOnExternalScreen(transfer)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">                        
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng-show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" class="ng-hide"></label>
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng-show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" class="ng-hide"></label>
                            <div>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng-click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="showUndoModal(transfer)">Undo</a>

                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng-click="executeWithdrawCommand(transfer)">Withdraw</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="showWithdrawModal(transfer)">Withdraw</a>


                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer) --><tr ng-repeat="transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer)">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class="{'highlight' : transfer.transferorBusinessId == CisBusinessID }" class="highlight">622402</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class="{'highlight' : transfer.transfereeBusinessId == CisBusinessID }">611485</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">Lease</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">18/04/2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">18/04/2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">4.00 entitlements @ €242.55</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">513453</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2016</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2017</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="transfer.isTransferHiddenForExternal" ng-show="true" ng-click="changeVisisbilityOfTransferOnExternalScreen(transfer)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">                        
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng-show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" class="ng-hide"></label>
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng-show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" class="ng-hide"></label>
                            <div>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng-click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="showUndoModal(transfer)">Undo</a>

                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng-click="executeWithdrawCommand(transfer)">Withdraw</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng-click="showWithdrawModal(transfer)">Withdraw</a>


                            </div>
                        </td>



                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer) -->
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

I have tried to create the following Xpath but it is returning every entitlements transferred box instead of only the ones which have the hide externally checkbox in the same row

```
("//td[contains(.,'entitlements @') and //tr[contains(.//@ng-class, 'transfer.transferorBusinessId == CisBusinessID')]//input[@type='checkbox' and @ng-show='true']]")
```

Comment: can u share html for row 1 which looks disabled?

Comment: Can you post complete DOM or provide your site?

Comment: Please provide the full input XML/HTML to make it a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following :

```
.//input[@ng-show='true']/ancestor::tr[1]/td[contains(text(),'entitlements @')]
```

depending on check box is enabled/disabled using ng-show true or false, this should work.

if you also have other checkboxes in Html, you can uniquely identify using ng-model. Use following xpath:

```
.//input[@ng-model='transfer.isTransferHiddenForExternal' and @ng-show='true']/ancestor::tr[1]/td[contains(text(),'entitlements @')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below xpath if you want to retrieve data from the Entitlements Transferred column based on the tr position.

```
.//input[@ng-show='true']/ancestor:://tr[position()>1]//td[contains(text(),'entitlements @')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `descendant`, try following `xpath`:

```
//tr[descendant::input[@ng-show='true']]//td[contains(text(),'entitlements @')]
```

[XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To select only the `<tr>` elements which have a `<td>` child which contains the text content "entitlements @" and doesn't display an `<input>` CheckBox, because `@ng-show` is FALSE, you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//tr[td[contains(text(),'entitlements @')] and td/div/input[@type='checkbox']/@ng-show='true']
```

To display some actual content, add some expression at the end.